# If $f$ is a $C^1$ function, show that if $Df(x)$ has linear independent rows, then $Df$ has linear independent rows in a neighbourhood of x

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^1$ function. Suppose that $Df(x)$ has linear independent rows. Prove that exists $r>0$ such that $Df(y)$ has linear independent rows for all $y \in B_r(x).$

Intuitively, the result holds since $Df(x)$, seen as a funtion of $x$, is a continuous function.
For the case $m=n$ I was able to prove it using that the determinant function is continuous.
What if $m \neq n$? What kind of property of the linear independence could I apply?

Comment: Why am I seeing "$f$" and "$f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^1$", for example, and not some formatted text?

Comment: If $m \lt n$, you can add $n-m$ functions and retain linear independence and then use your result for $m=n$.  If $m \gt n$, add dummy variables and again use your result for $m=n$.

Comment: A rectangular matrix has full rank if and only if the determinants of the maximal minors do not simultaneously vanish. For example, if the matrix $M$ has $n$ rows and $m > n$ columns, then there are $\binom{m}{n}$ ways of selecting columns to form an $n \times n$ submatrix: taking the determinants of these matrices gives a map $\varphi \colon \operatorname{Mat}_{n, m}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{\binom{m}{n}}$, and a matrix $M$ is full rank if and only if $\varphi(M) \neq 0$. Then you should be able to apply continuity as before.

Comment: Note that $A$ has li. rows **iff** $ \det (A A^T) >0$.